# Play Spotify Audio from my web

Tags: cakephp, spotify

Currently, I've registered a spotify account. I want to use my own player to play Spotify track, with controls: pause, seek, play. Spotify provides Web Playback SDK but it is restricted for premium account only, if use embeded widget then it only play 30s and can't seek. Do you have any suggestion for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find out, use Spotify Web Playback SDK but users must use a Premium account to listen audio track.

> Ref:
>   https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/